# Force array as object with numbered keys in Firebase REST API

Tags: arrays, object, firebase

I'm using Firebase to host enumerated values that describe various events, for example (man, I wish StackOverflow supported markdown tables):

```
| Enumeration | Description |
| ----------- | ----------- |
| 0           | A description of a low-priority event. |
| 1           | A description of a critical event. |
```

I'm storing that data in Firebase as follows:

```
"enumerations": {
  "events": { 
    "0": {
      "description": "A description of a low-priority event."
    },
    "1": {
      "description": "A description of a critical event." 
    }
  }
}
```

The plan is to have a user download the list of enumerations using the [Firebase Rest API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/) with both the `?print=pretty` and `?download=filename` request parameters, like so:

```
https://FIREBASE_NAME.firebaseio.com/enumerations/events.json?print=pretty&download=events.json
```

But the data that is received looks like the following:

```
[ {
  "description": "A description of a low-priority event."
},
{
  "description": "A description of a critical event."
} ]
```

Now, I know *why* this happens - 
I've read the ["Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase"](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) article. I understand how Firebase interprets objects that *look* like arrays and then returns them as array, but, in my case I would really like a way to force Firebase to return a JSON object with numbered keys as they are stored in Firebase.

I'd like a solution that keeps the formatting of the table as is rather than naming the keys something like "event1", "event2", etc. Again, this is really only for the REST API, as it would be easy to do this in code, but this is for an external user to download directly from Firebase, so potentially having a URL request parameter `?forceAsArray=true` would be a nice solution.

Or maybe I'm overlooking something in the documentation - Is this possible today?

Comment: Also see: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase (docs > blog posts, when it comes to being up-to-date and this authoritative). You can easily loop over the results and convert them back into your preferred format.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, thanks for the link, but my question was tailored to forcing the result of the request to an object **in the browser**. If I was parsing over the results, yes, this would be easy, but the current strategy is to provide a read-only link to 3rd-party clients so that they can easily see the list of enumerated values.